# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_2 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-classification

I was trying to use the model that I trained to check on the images passed to it, however, it failed to use the image I passed.

The code:

```
path_img = pathlib.Path("D:/Python Projects/Final Year Project/assets/resource/train_images/Acinetobacter.baumanii/edited/img0.png")
image = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(path_img, target_size=(self.image_height, self.image_width))
image_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
image_array = tf.expand_dims(image_array, 0)
prediction = self.imgReg.model.predict(image_array )
```

I tried to run the code for detecting the prediction of the image, and I got this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 50176 but received input with shape [None, 57600]
```

I used the same image and model in Google Colabs and it works there but when running it on my local computer, it just doesn't work the same, how do I fix this?

Comment: Btw, I am using Tensorflow 2.4.0-dev20200704 and the one on Google Colab is using 2.3.0, does that matter?

Comment: Nvrmind, that was not the case, tested it already

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error,you need to do below changes in your code:

```
image_array = tf.expand_dims(image_array, -1)
```